# PHP cURL Request Not Following Redirects

Tags: php, redirect, curl, web-crawler

We have a crawler built in PHP to pull vital information from our clients' pages. The issue is that most of our clients post custom shortened links that use a 302 to go to the final destination. Our crawler has been successful in following these (see the code below) up until this latest client. Here's a sample link:

http://www.dose.com/lists/26235/s

If you go there in a browser, you'll see the standard 302 behavior, but if you visit it with a crawler, it simply returns a 200 and doesn't redirect. This led me to believe that I had to make the request look as "natural" as possible, but I still haven't had any success. Finally, here's the cURL section of our code:

```
function sendRequest($url)
{
    global $ch;
    $user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.7.5)".
                " Gecko/20041107 Firefox/1.0";
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8',
        'Connection: keep-alive'
    ));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');

    $contents = curl_exec($ch);
    //curl_close($ch);

    return $contents;
}
```

Edited to include the advice from below, although the issue still persists.

Comment: http://www.dose.com/lists/26235/s - returns '301 Moved permanently'

Comment: You are correct. Thanks for that correction. Still not quite sure why cURL is having such a hard time with it.

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't already, you'll need to manually inflate the response of that function using **gzdecode()**

An even better way might be to tell Curl to handle the compression itself, rather than manually specifying it. Try removing the Accept-Encoding header line and adding:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');
```

Comment: Thanks for this tip. The headers are a new addition in an attempt to fix this issue, so I hadn't considered this. Unfortunately the issue still persists.